# Does a bounty chop?

Tags: tournament, home-game

In a poker tournament with a bounty on a player, the all in player was against two others at the table. The two remaining players chopped the hand and beat the all in.

We split the side pot and the main pot, but weren't sure how to credit 'who' got the bounty, and whether we should split the value of the bounty prize or double the prize.

By the way the pot goes, it would make sense to split the bounty prize (if it were monetary) but there was a 'token' object prize as well.

So, the two part question is: Does one chop or double a bounty prize and how does one record that when tracking such things?

Comment: Please make sure you address the situation of what to do when the bounty is not monetary but an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my experience It depends....

If going all in three way handed and the loosing player has the low stack, the other two players split the bounty.

If the loosing player has more chips than one of the other players, the bounty is not split
and "goes" to the player with the high stack.

I know you didn't ask but to complete the answer.. in split pot games like Omaha hi-low and 
7-stud hi-low, the bounty is always earned by the winner of the high hand.

Regards,
Amigal

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen and the rule that was applied was the bounty went to the player with the most chips a the start of the hand.

Comment: Can you give more details to the environment on this? Home-game vs card room vs casino, Type of tourney, and what the bounty was?

Comment: Hi yes this was in a casino cardroom and a ruling was called and that was the ruling.

Answer (score 0):

At my casino (Red Rock, Las Vegas), the bounties are split evenly between any winning players in the hand.
It's usually two other winners and the bounty is $20.  So one winner hands the other a $10 bill and then gets to keep the $20 bounty card to turn in for cash later.